# Use atributes of shortcode in get template part

Tags: shortcode, widgets, templates

Hi guys im doing a custom shortcode where the client can set a custom taxonomy and display in my sidebar

I want to use a template using the  `get_template_part` but i dont get the terms of the taxonomy

I'm using the following code to display the shortcode

```
function cat_widgets( $atts ) {
    ob_start();
    get_template_part('templates/show-taxonomy');
    return ob_get_clean();
} 
add_shortcode( 'cat_widgets', 'cat_widgets' );

add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode' );
```

And in the show-taxonomy.php my code is

```
<?php
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'custom_taxonomy' => '',
    ), $atts, 'atributes' );
    $terms_categorias = get_terms([
        'taxonomy' => $atts['custom_taxonomy'],
        'hide_empty' => false,
        'orderby' => 'term_id',
        'order' => 'ASC' 
    ]);
    ?>
    
    <ul class="product-categories">
        <?php foreach($terms_categorias as $term): ?>
            <li class="cat-item">
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_term_link($term) ); ?>">
                    <?php echo esc_html($term->name); ?>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
```

I also tried to put the atts and get the terms in the shortcode after de ob_start(); but the returns is the same

Is there something that im missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$atts` in your template part (`templates/show-taxonomy.php`) *that you passed to [`shortcode_atts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/shortcode_atts/)* is not defined, so you need to define it by passing it via the **third parameter** for [`get_template_part()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/) like this:

```php
get_template_part( 'templates/show-taxonomy', '', array( 'atts' => $atts ) );
```

Then in the template part, use `$args['atts']` to access the shortcode parameters:

```php
$atts = shortcode_atts( array(
    'custom_taxonomy' => '',
), $args['atts'], 'atributes' ); // here, use $args['atts'] and not $atts
```

And actually, in the above `shortcode_atts()` call, the third parameter should be `cat_widgets` (i.e. the 1st parameter for `add_shortcode()`) and not `atributes`. :)

Comment: It works wonderfull, thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it helped! :-) (PS: I revised my answer a bit - mainly to reword the first paragraph).